# routes.MapRoute - this webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Login",
    url: "login",
    defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Server",
    url: "server/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Client", 
     url: "{*url}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
if (!UserNotLoggedIn)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Index");
}
```

The logic: All request go to `Home/Index` (I'm using angular for routing). 
In the `HomeController` I check if the user is logged in. If so, I return a view. If not, I want to redirect the user to login.
The problem is that when the user is not logged in he is redirected to mydomain/login but gets "This webpage has a redirect loop". When I run with debugger, I see that even if the url is `/login` the controller and action is still `Home/Index`.

Comment: Why are you not using MVC authentication? If you need to customize it, you just need to subclass [`Authorize`] attribute. At the very least, you should be using an `IAuthorizationFilter` implementation to do this check rather than putting it into a controller action.

Answer (score 0):

You got the `RedirectToAction()` arguments in the wrong order. First is the action name, then the controller:

```
protected internal RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName);
```

And in your case:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
```

Your current `RedirectToAction` call probably returns an empty string which causes the browser to 'redirect' to the same page once again, getting the same redirection results again, and you're ending up with a redirect-loop.

Also, you better use the `Authorize` filter instead of performing your own authentication and redirection mechanism.

See [Authentication and Authorization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx)

Comment: I tried to replace to "return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");" But still I get "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Comment: Are there any global filters registered? Did you try to decorate the `Login/Index` action with `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute?

Comment: I'm not using MVC Authentication so [AllowAnonymous] will not work anyway. In FilterConfig.cs there is just "filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());" (The generic file that created in the project creation by the visual studio)

Comment: Are the routes defined exactly in the order you pasted? It might be that the `Client` route (with the `"{*url}"` pattern) is taking over the `/Login` request. Try to comment that out temporarily.

Comment: In this case I get HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72212/discussion-between-mosh-and-haim770).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the route definition.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Login",
    url: "login",
    defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index" }
```

Here the expected url doesn't match login/index.

Unfortunately the matched url is

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Client", 
    url: "{*url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
```

Which makes it go back to home/index.  Try changing the url format of "login" and pass an url which matches  it and your problem should be fixed.
When using fixed urls, you should be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that you need to be logged in to view the login page, please make sure your login page does not have the Authorize attribute, either in the controller or the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a MapRoute with a returnUrl. I like to redirect my users to the requested URL upon registration & login.

```
         routes.MapRoute(
         null,
         "{controller}/{id}",
         new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" },
         new { returnUrl = @"regex for URLs" });
```